# HTTParty response: GET image and convert bytes to base64 image data url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, base64, httparty

I am trying to download an image, and then return a base64 data url.

```rb
img = HTTParty.get('https://via.placeholder.com/150')
=> "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00..."

base64_img = Base64.encode64(img)
=> "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAACWBAMAAADOL2zRAAA..."

data_url = "data:image/png;base64," + base64_img
=> "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAA..."
```

When I paste that image into my browser it *should* render. Yet it is not valid. What am I doing wrong, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Base64.strict_encode64(img)` instead of `encode64(img)`